# Restoring purged mysql binlog files

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog

I've got a replication set up on pair of servers. One is a master and second is a slave.

Recently on master the binlog files were purged too early (by filename so mysql haven't prevented too early removal of file).

Now the SLAVE has status:

> Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'

I wan't to restore the missing binlog files so the slave will restart reading from the point it finished.

The files are already in place but how can I force master to 'unpurge' it's log list (so they are visible in SHOW BINARY LOGS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I made it. However this solution isn't perfect/100% safe.

I've entered all filenames to my mysql-bin.index

```
find /var/log/mysql/ -wholename '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.0*' | sort > mysql-bin.index
```

(if you will use it check the filename format in mysql-bin.index file first and adjust to your needs)

Then restart mysql and mysql reloads that file on start.

the MASTER is ready.

Now it's enough to do

```
SLAVE STOP;
```

and

```
SLAVE START;
```

on SLAVE and it will continue his job.